# Playing Video with multiple instance

Tags: android, video, vlc

I am trying to Play RTMP Video using android vlc sdk with multiple instance in a screen like atleast two video instance the problem is that at a time its play only one video

```
    package com.example.ajeet.libvlc;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Surface;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.VideoView;
    import org.videolan.libvlc.IVideoPlayer;
    import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
    import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVlcException;
    public class VideoVLCActivity extends Activity implements IVideoPlayer
   {
        private static final String TAG = VideoVLCActivity.class.getSimpleName();

       //Size of Video
       private int mVideoHeight;
       private int mVideoWidth;
       private int mVideoVisibleHeight;
       private int mVideoVisibleWidth;
       private int mSarNum;
       private int mSarDen;
       private SurfaceView mSurfaceView1,mSurfaceView2;
       private FrameLayout mSurfaceFrame1,mSurfaceFrame2;
       private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder1,mSurfaceHolder2;
       private Surface mSurface1,mSurface2 = null;
       public LibVLC mLibVLC1,mLibVLC2;
       private String mMediaUrl1,mMediaUrl2;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "VideoVLC -- onCreate -- START ------------");   setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_vlc2);

        //For first player
        mSurfaceView1 = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.player_surface1);
        mSurfaceHolder1 = mSurfaceView1.getHolder();

        mSurfaceFrame1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.player_surface_frame1);
        mMediaUrl1= getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoUrl");

        try {
            mLibVLC1 = new LibVLC();
            mLibVLC1.setAout(mLibVLC1.AOUT_AUDIOTRACK);
            mLibVLC1.setVout(mLibVLC1.VOUT_ANDROID_SURFACE);
            mLibVLC1.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);

            mLibVLC1.init(getApplicationContext());
        }catch (LibVlcException e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }

        mSurface1 = mSurfaceHolder1.getSurface();

        mLibVLC1.attachSurface(mSurface1, VideoVLCActivity.this);
        mLibVLC1.playMRL(mMediaUrl1);


        //For SecondPlayer

        mSurfaceView2 =(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.player_surface2);
        mSurfaceHolder2 = mSurfaceView2.getHolder();

       mSurfaceFrame2 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.player_surface_frame2);
        mMediaUrl2= getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoUrl");
        try {
            mLibVLC2 = new LibVLC();
            mLibVLC2.setAout(mLibVLC2.AOUT_AUDIOTRACK);
            mLibVLC2.setVout(mLibVLC2.VOUT_ANDROID_SURFACE);
            mLibVLC2.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
            mLibVLC2.init(getApplicationContext());
        }catch (LibVlcException e){
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
        mSurface2 = mSurfaceHolder2.getSurface();
        mLibVLC2.attachSurface(mSurface2,VideoVLCActivity.this);
        mLibVLC2.playMRL(mMediaUrl2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // MediaCodec opaque direct rendering should not be used anymore since there is no surface to attach.
        mLibVLC1.stop();
        mLibVLC2.stop();
    }
    public void eventHardwareAccelerationError() {
        Log.e(TAG, "eventHardwareAccelerationError()!");
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSurfaceLayout(final int width, final int height, int visible_width, int visible_height, final int sar_num, int sar_den){
        Log.d(TAG, "setSurfaceSize -- START");
        if (width * height == 0)
            return;

        // store video size
        mVideoHeight = height;
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoVisibleHeight = visible_height;
        mVideoVisibleWidth = visible_width;
        mSarNum = sar_num;
        mSarDen = sar_den;

        Log.d(TAG, "setSurfaceSize -- mMediaUrl: " + mMediaUrl1 + " mVideoHeight: " + mVideoHeight + " mVideoWidth: " + mVideoWidth + " mVideoVisibleHeight: " + mVideoVisibleHeight + " mVideoVisibleWidth: " + mVideoVisibleWidth + " mSarNum: " + mSarNum + " mSarDen: " + mSarDen);
        Log.d(TAG, "setSurfaceSize -- mMediaUrl: " + mMediaUrl2 + " mVideoHeight: " + mVideoHeight + " mVideoWidth: " + mVideoWidth + " mVideoVisibleHeight: " + mVideoVisibleHeight + " mVideoVisibleWidth: " + mVideoVisibleWidth + " mSarNum: " + mSarNum + " mSarDen: " + mSarDen);
    }

    @Override
    public int configureSurface(android.view.Surface surface, int i, int i1, int i2){
        return -1;
    }
}
```

here is the code please help

Comment: Hi.Have u got any solution?

Comment: not yet do you have any idea

Comment: Did u see this:-[Android VLC player with multiple instance](https://github.com/dariobanfi/multiplevlc)